# How to add a secondary parent to an Alfresco document

Tags: alfresco

In Alfresco, a single document can have several parent folders. Example mydoc.txt can be found both in folder1 and folder2.

**QUESTION**: How to easily create such a situation, without coding?

I want to create this kind of structure in order to perform tests. The faster the better. Alfresco used to have a [JavaScript Console](https://github.com/share-extras/js-console) that allowed this but it was not very easy and now it is not shipped with Alfresco anymore so you have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install CMIS Workbench
2. Connect to your Alfresco server
3. Copy the ID of the folder you want to set as a secondary parent:

[image: CMIS Workbench folder object id]

4. Go to the document, select the `Actions` tab, find the `Add Object to Folder` section, paste the ID in the `Folder Id` field and press `Add`:

[image: CMIS Workbench, Add Object to Folder]